# Twilio Node JS - filter sms per phone number

Tags: node.js, rest, twilio

I would like to filter sms per phone number and date the SMS was sent using REST API, however the output of the following code is not available outside of client.messages.each() block.
Please advise how I can use the latest sms code sent to the filtered number:

```
const filterOpts = {
  to: '+13075550185',
  dateSent: moment().utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
};
let pattern = /([0-9]{1,})$/;
let codeCollection = [];
client.messages.each(filterOpts, (record) => {
  codeCollection.push(record.body.match(pattern)[0]);
  console.log(record.body.match(pattern)[0], record.dateSent);
 });
 console.log(codeCollection,'I get an empty array here');//how to get 
 the latest sms and use it 
 doSomethingWithSMS(codeCollection[0]);
```

Comment: The `console.log` where you're getting an empty array is likely being executed before the internals of the callback function with your `record` being pushed. Try logging within the `.each` after its been pushed to `codeCollection`

Comment: yes. But I need to call another function outside of the .each() and just use the latest sms code. The console.log inside of each() returns all codes for that phone number sent today.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [`each` function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-node/3.13.0/Twilio.Api.V2010.AccountContext.MessageList.html#each) doesn't actually return a `Promise`. You can run a callback function after `each` has completed streaming results by passing it into the options as `done` like this:

```
const codeCollection = [];
const pattern = /([0-9]{1,})$/;

const filterOpts = {
  to: '+13075550185',
  dateSent: moment().utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
  done: (err) => {
    if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
    console.log(codeCollection);
    doSomethingWithSMS(codeCollection[0]);
  }
};

client.messages.each(filterOpts, (record) => {
  codeCollection.push(record.body.match(pattern)[0]);
  console.log(record.body.match(pattern)[0], record.dateSent);
 });
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the length of the array of messages? If so, you can do something like this

```
const filterOpts = {
  to: '+13075550185',
  dateSent: moment().utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
};
let pattern = /([0-9]{1,})$/;
let codeCollection = [];
var i = 0
client.messages.each(filterOpts, (record) => {
    if (i < messages.length){
        codeCollection.push(record.body.match(pattern)[0]);
        console.log(record.body.match(pattern)[0], record.dateSent);
        i++;
    else {
        nextFunction(codeCollection);
    }
 });

function nextFunction(codeCollection){
     console.log(codeCollection,'I get an empty array here');
     doSomethingWithSMS(codeCollection[0]);
}
```

Comment: You wouldn't, you'd have to perform a separate asynchronous call to get the messages count.

Comment: I don't have access to that array outside of client.messages.each()
I can preview output inside of that block but not outside. Cannot also use .then to chain promiss since looks that client.messages.each doesn't return a promiss

Answer (score 0):

`messages.each()` is running asynchronously, so your main thread moves on to the next call while the `client.messages()` stuff runs on a background thread.  So, nothing has been pushed to codeCollection by the time you've tried to access it. You need to somehow wait for the each() to finish before moving on. Twilio client uses backbone style promises, so you can just add another .then() link to the chain, like below. You could also use a library like async which lets you use await to write asynchronous code in a more linear looking fashion.

```
const filterOpts = {
  to: '+13075550185',
  dateSent: moment().utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
};
let pattern = /([0-9]{1,})$/;
let codeCollection = [];
client.messages.each(filterOpts, (record) => {
    codeCollection.push(record.body.match(pattern)[0]);
    console.log(record.body.match(pattern)[0], record.dateSent);
}).then(
    function() {
        console.log(codeCollection,'I get an empty array here');
        if( codeCollection.count > 0 ) doSomethingWithSMS(codeCollection[0]);
    }
);
```

Comment: A question.. do libraries need to offer support for async/promises to be able to use .then() for example?

Comment: @db2791 From my experience, all libraries that I've used that had asynchronous functionality were compatible with backbone style promises, i.e. .then() worked.  Not to say that it's a universal truth, but I've never explicitly included backbone with any of my projects and have always used .then() when working with asynchronasity.

Comment: async is a separate library that makes working with asynchronous functions way cleaner.  I believe it's actually built into later versions of node.  Maybe it's node that includes backbone style promises by default? All of my javascript apps have used node.  So, I'm sorry I can't explicitly answer your question, but I hope this helps.

Comment: seems Twilio runs the code synchronously, and thus I get Cannot read property 'then' of undefined if I want to chain promise. Basically console.log() inside of each block shows the output so the code must be synchronous.
Output of console.log inside of each block is eg:
3164 2018-03-02T13:56:39.000Z
0778 2018-03-02T13:54:49.000Z
1883 2018-03-02T13:51:22.000Z
7753 2018-03-02T13:50:04.000Z

Comment: but still, how to get record outside of each block??Provided solution doesn't work

Comment: You can't access a block scoped variable from outside of the block.  Put things in a function scope variable.  And you need to use the blocks, If you put something outside of your promise chain it will get executed before the asynchronous promise chain stuff gets executed, thus will still be undefined.